# Rails 4: jQuery modal form with fall from the top effect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I need a little help with Rails and jQuery modal.

How to add the "fall from the top" effect to a modal window in Rails 4?
I'm not using Bootstrap and I don't pretend to use it.
I'm just opening the modal popup with:

```
<%= link_to_modal 'New User Modal Sized', new_user_path, :width=> "600", :height =>"400", :remote => true %><BR/>
```

I'm just following the code from https://github.com/dei79/jquery-modal-rails

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at [these CSS3 transition effects](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). There are a lot of great ones and one does the desired behavior you're looking for. I've tested these with a Bootstrap modal and they work, so it should be an easy integration into your modal.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

You would add the classes `animated slideInDown` on the modal, not the link.

That being said, I'm an advocate of using CSS3 animations/transitions when appropriate, but others would argue using JavaScript is better.